# como poner limite al leer un fichero por lineas en java

Tags: java

Quiero leer un fichero y separar sus lineas en un array, el problema es que no se como ponerle limite a la lectura. Es decir, luego de que copia la ultima linea, y el próximo dato sea null, que finalice.

Espero haberme explicado, dejo el fragmento del código

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivo.txt"));
String linea = br.readLine();

String[] values = linea.split("");
String lineacortada[] = new String[values.length];

//for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (null != values) {
        lineacortada[i] = br.readLine(); //
        System.out.println(lineacortada[i]); //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola La Condición de Lectura del Archivo la puedes colocar dentro de un While o un For como el siguiente ejemplo.

De esta Manera se realizara la Lectura hasta que termine las lineas del Archivo y a medida que recorres las lineas cargas tu Array.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo.txt"));
        String linea = null;
        System.err.println("br.read():"+br.read());
        String[] palabras=new String[br.read()];
        for (int i = 0; (linea=br.readLine())!=null; i++) {
            System.out.println(linea);
            palabras[i]=linea;
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lineas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lineas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Lineas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quisieras detener el for cuando encuentre un nulo simplemente agrega un **break** si no entra a tu if:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (null != values) {
            lineacortada[i] = br.readLine(); //
            System.out.println(lineacortada[i]); //

        } else {
            System.out.println("se encontró un nulo");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilice un while en lugar del for.
el archivo.ready() sigue leyendo lineas hasta que se acaban...

```
while (archivo.ready()) {   // Lo recorre mientras !eof()

 }
```

Comment: Mau. La pregunta trata sobre cómo detener la ejecución del for si una condición se cumple. También en tu respuesta tienes un **archivo.ready()**, cosa que en la pregunta nunca se menciona. Puedes mejorar un poco tu respuesta explicando **por qué** la porción de código que escribes resuelve el problema.